# React Native ListView Cannot read property '_currentElement' of null

Tags: javascript, listview, reactjs, react-native

I'm working with ReactNative for the first time. I'm trying to build a `ListView` based off what a api returns. Here is my component:

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var api = require('../utils/api');

var {
  ActivityIndicatorIOS,
  ListView,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  TouchableHighlight,
  View
} = React;

class CheckIn extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoading: false,
      dataSource: new ListView.DataSource({
       rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2
      })
    };
  }
  search(searchTerm) {
    api.search(searchTerm)
      .then((response) => {
        this.setState({
          isLoading: false,
          dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(response)
        })
      });
  }
  renderCustomRow(row) {
    return (
      <TouchableHighlight style={styles.row}>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text>{row.name}</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    );
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{marginTop: 65}}>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.search}
          placeholder="Search"
          onChangeText={(text) => {
            this.search(text);
            this.setState({isLoading: true});
          }}/>
        <ListView
          dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
          renderRow={this.renderCustomRow.bind(this)}
          style={styles.listView} />
        <ActivityIndicatorIOS
          animating={this.state.isLoading}
          color='#111'
          size="large"></ActivityIndicatorIOS>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  search: {
    height: 40,
    padding: 5,
    borderBottomWidth: 2,
    borderBottomColor: '#000'
  }
});

module.exports = CheckIn;
```

When I type one letter into the search bar, the activity indicator appears, the api returns a valid JSON response (checked with console.log), and then the activity indicator should disappear, but it doesn't. If I type a second letter, I get the following error:

`Cannot read property '_currentElement' of null`

[image]

Anything I seem to be missing?

I'm using ReactNative 0.14, npm is version 3.5

Comment: I'm shooting from the hip here, but I think you need to change this ` .then((response)` to this ` .then((response.json(()`. I could try harder once I'm at a computer

Comment: @ChrisGeirman thanks for your response! I should mention that my api component returns the response like so: `return fetch(url).then((response) => response.json());`

Comment: ah, gotcha... can you set this up on rnplay.org?

Comment: I'm not near my computer with the code, so I was using a sample api just now setting it up on rnplay.org and it got me thinking that it may be my api causing the issue. When I get near the computer tonight I'll try it and if that doesn't fix it, I'll post it with the api code as well. Thanks @ChrisGeirman!

Comment: @ChrisGeirman my api was returning a nested result within a root node, instead of an array. Whoops! :) Thanks for being so willing to help!

Comment: glad to hear you f figured it out.